# Complete kotlin flow successfully and emit partially data on some condition

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I'm struggling to get completed flow with some result without any exception on some condition. Let's say I'm receiving flow of lists. I want to emit some of its data and then complete without any exception, for example:

```
class FlowTest {

    @Test
    internal fun `should emit partially when some condition fulfilled`() = runTest {
        val testFlow = flowOf(listOf(1,2), listOf(3,4), listOf(5,6))
            .transform {
                if(it.contains(4)) {
                    emit(it[0])
                    cancel()
                } else {
                    emit(it[0])
                    emit(it[1])
                }
            }

        assertEquals(3, testFlow.toList().size, "Should contain [1,2,3]")
    }
}
```

It fails because of `JobCancellationException`. I could also make some filter and emit specific things, but then `listOf(5,6)` would also go through filters and this is bad since I'd like to close flow as early as some condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`transformWhile`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/transform-while.html). This lets you return a `true` or `false` value indicating whether to continue the flow.

```kotlin
.transformWhile {
    if(it.contains(4)) {
        emit(it[0])
        false // stop the flow
    } else {
        emit(it[0])
        emit(it[1])
        true // continue the flow
    }
}
```